# How do I make use of a custom .d.ts file in a Visual Studio Code project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I have an app that consumes a lot of custom objects and arrays that I have defined in a separate **MyInterfaces.d.ts** file. This file looks something like this:

```
export type IGenericObj = {
  [key: string]: any;
}

export interface IReactJsonObj {
  component: string;
  key: number;
  props: {
    className?: string;
    id: number;
    to?: string;
    query?: string;
    src?: string;
    alt?: string;
    height?: number;
    children?: IReactJsonObj[];
  };
}

export interface IReactSideProps {
  amount: number;
  height: number;
  name: string;
  width: number;
}
```

Right now, in every one of my files, where I want to use these definitions I have to put this at the top of my files:

```
import { IGenericObj, IReactJsonObj, IReactSideProps } from '../../../../../../types/MyInterfaces';
```

There has to be a better way right? I want these definitions to be available everywhere in my project, because I'm using them all the time, so tired putting this in my tsconfig.json file:

```
"typeRoots": [
  "../../../../../../types/MyInterfaces",
  "./node_modules/@types"
]
```

But now I am still stuck, how am I supposed to use **IGenericObj** in one of my files? If I start typing IGene... it doesn't show anything in intelisense, and I can't just use it, because it's undefined, like I could **Promise** for example.

Answer (score 0):

`typeRoots` should refer to a directory, not a file. Try `"../../../../../../types"`, and make sure the path is relative to your project root rather than the file where you're trying to use the types.

Additionally, if you want the types to be available globally rather than through imports, you should use `declare` instead of `export`. I personally find this a little too global variable-y for my liking, but it might fit your use-case.

**EDIT:** [Apparently `declare interface`/`declare type` is just a synonym for `interface`/`type` in a `.d.ts` file, so removing the `export` keywords ought to have the same effect.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1940)

Comment: I've done this, but what is the next step? How do I actually use these definitions in my project? If I start typing IGenericObj nothing is happening. What should I be putting inside my Component.tsx files, so that I have direct access to my definitions?

Comment: @Amir: Updated my answer.

Comment: @Amir: Also, if your `d.ts` file is within your project folder and you're using declarations instead of imports, I don't think you need to amend `typeRoots` at all. Apparently the convention is to have an [`interfaces.d.ts`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/src/interfaces.d.ts) in your project that contains these kinds of global definitions.

Comment: I just can't seem to get it to work. I've changed the file to use declare instead of export, I've tried moving the file out of the @types folder into the root project directly and they still don't show up in my .jsx files. What has changed however, is that two sibling files ex: one.d.ts and two.d.ts have access to declarations declared in each one of them. I just need this behavior now for the whole project. I've also tried removing typeRoots and also no success.

Comment: Didn't work for me neither. Tried calling file `interfaces.d.ts`, `main.d.ts`, but still intellisense doesn't work. But Intellisense WORKS when I have the xx.d.ts file open as one of the tabs in VSCode! :O